# How would I find the formula for the quotient of complex numbers in polar form?

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-explanation

The formula for multiplying complex numbers is very neat and tidy, and you can get to it by FOILing and substituting identities:

$z_{1} = r_{1}(\cos\theta_{1}+i\sin\theta_{1})~~~~~~~z_{2} = r_{2}(\cos\theta_{2}+i\sin\theta_{2})$

$z_{1}z_{2} = r_{1}(\cos\theta_{1}+i\sin\theta_{1})r_{2}(\cos\theta_{2}+i\sin\theta_{2})$

$= r_{1}r_{2}(\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2} + i\cos\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2} + i\sin\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2} + i^{2}\sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2})$

$= r_{1}r_{2}(\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2} - \sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2} + i[\cos\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2} + \sin\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}])$

$= r_{1}r_{2}(\cos(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}) + i\sin(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}))$

$\implies z_{1}z_{2} = r_{1}r_{2}(\cos(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}) + i\sin(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}))$

How would I go about doing this for the quotient of two complex numbers? I have only ever been given the formula directly, without the explanation of why it is true:

$\frac{z_1}{z_2}=\frac{r_1}{r_2}(\cos(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2}) + i\sin(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2}))$

Comment: Start with your two formulas you have at top for z1 and z2 but this time divide. You see the divisions of r part, and for divisions of the cos +i sin use the trick of multiplying top and bottom by the complex conjugate. [you'll need to apply the difference formulas for sine and cosine]

Comment: Understand the polar form of $1/z$ in terms of the polar form of $z$.